# Get your apps ready for the 64-bit requirement: What to do if I have no .so files in my apk (Android)?

Tags: android, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have received a newsletter from Google:
"Get your apps ready for the 64-bit requirement"

This is the link:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

It says: " If you do not have any .so files in your APK, you are already 64-bit compliant."

So, I have no "lib" directory nor ".so" files in my app. I guess it is 64-bit compliant.

Is there any thing to do ?

Is there any flag to check in the Google Play Console to mark the app as 64 bit compliant ?

Can I just ignore the newsletter ?

Comment: Yes you can ignore the newsletter, your not running any native code that you have generated in your apk. 'Google Play' check you are compliant.

Comment: Thanks. This could be the answer then.

Answer (score 4):

`Is there anything to do ?`

Not really, you can simply ignore since you are not doing native development here.
So you can simply ignore the newsletter.

`Is there any flag to check in the Google Play Console to mark the app as 64 bit compliant ?`

No, if you are developing apps using the Android SDK and have no native (NDK) code, then it is already 64-bit compliant.